# finding pole of order m of a function

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help me with this question:

Suppose that a function $f$ has a pole of order $m$ at $z = 0$, and

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle|z|^\frac{3}{2}} \le |f(z)| \le \displaystyle\frac{1}{\displaystyle|z|^\frac{5}{2}}$

for all $z$ satisfying $0 \le |z| \le 1$. Find $m$.

Ans: m = 2.
Hint given: Define $f(z)$ = $\displaystyle\frac{\phi(z)}{(z-0)^m}$ near $z=0$, where $\phi(f(z))$ is analytic at $z=0$ with $\phi(0) \neq 0$. Need to show a contradiction for these two cases: when $m \ge 3$ and when $m \le 1$ by considering limits of the form $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to 0} |\phi(z) . z^\alpha|$ for suitable $\alpha$'s.

Answer (score 1):

You have pretty much the whole solution given.

Call $\phi_m(z):=z^mf(z)$. Then

$$|z|^{m-1/2}\leq \phi_m|(z)|\leq|z|^{m-5/2}.$$

If $m<2$ then, using the first inequality we get that $\phi_2(z)\rightarrow\infty$ when $z\rightarrow 0$. Therefore the pole is of order $\geq2$.

If $m=3$ then we get, from the second inequality $|f(z)|\leq |z|^{1/2}$. Therefore $\phi_3(z)$ is bounded near $z=0$. Therefore the pole is of order $\leq3$. But the inequality tells us more. It says also that $\phi_3(z)\rightarrow0$ as $z\rightarrow0$. Therefore the order of the pole is $<3$.